# DHCP DDNS + Samba AD?

Tags: active-directory, bind, dhcp, isc-dhcp, dynamic-dns

I'm working on moving a small business network away from a Windows Small Business Server. I've set up the active directory using Samba, and it all works well, but I see one potential problem: Currently we depend somewhat heavily on DHCP-based dynamic DNS, so that our workflow can look like this:

1. Spin up a VM
2. Change its hostname in the remote console
3. Reboot
4. SSH in with the hostname we just set

However, it seems like that would conflict with Samba's AD-based DDNS. Can we reconcile the two somehow? Our DNS backend for Samba is BIND9_DLZ, and the DHCP server we're moving to is isc_dhcp_server, although that is flexible.